# C# Anonymous User Authorization Failure

Tags: c#, authorization, web-config

I am trying to set up a forms authentication application where all pages are accessible to authenticated users with the exception of the login page which is open to all or anonymous users.

I set up web.config like below:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="3"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    ...
</system.web>
....
<location path="Login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
            <!--  also tried this
            <allow users="*"/>
            -->
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I also set the start page (in VS 2019) to login.aspx. When I run it I still get:

```
Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. The server may not be configured for access to the requested URL.

Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by moving login.aspx to a folder (I called it Account). I added a web.config in this folder with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I removed the "location" part from main web.config. So it looks like:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="3"/>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    ....
</system.web>
```